# Не работает комментирование в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, php

Здравствуйте.

Есть такая проблема: у меня на сайте комментирование новостей реализовано с помощью модальных окон. При нажатии на ссылку "Подробнее" открывается модальное окно со всей новостью и внизу комментирование. Комментирование реализовано с помощью *AJAX*, но комментирование начинает работать только с 4-5 раза, т.е. обновляем страницу, нажимаем "подробнее", открывается окно, но комментирование не работает. А начинает работать только с 4-5 открывания модального окна. Скрипт добавления комментария находится в содержимом модального окна.

В чем подвох? Очень жду Вашей помощи.

```
<?

session_start();
include ("blocks/bd.php");// файл bd.php должен быть в той же папке, что и все    остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь 

if (!empty($_SESSION['login']) and !empty($_SESSION['password']))
{
//если существует логин и пароль в сессиях, то проверяем, действительны ли они
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,lastname FROM users WHERE login='$login'   AND password='$password'",$db); 
$myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

if (empty($myrow2['id']))
{
//Если не действительны, то закрываем доступ
exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!");}}
else {
//Проверяем, зарегистрирован ли вошедший
exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!"); }

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {$id = $_POST['id'];
print <<<HERE
HERE;
$resulttext = mysql_query("SELECT id,news,author,cat,date,d_ord FROM post WHERE     id='$id'",$db); 
$myrowtext = mysql_fetch_array($resulttext);
$dates2 = date("Y-m-d");
if (substr ($myrowtext['d_ord'], 0, 10) == substr($dates2,0,10)) {$myrowtext['date'] = "сегодня ".substr($myrowtext['date'],6 )."";}
if (substr ($myrowtext['d_ord'],0,8) == substr($dates2,0,8) AND substr ($myrowtext['d_ord'],8) == substr($dates2,8) - 1) {$myrowtext['date'] = "вчера ".substr($myrowtext['date'],6 )."";}

if ($myrowtext['cat'] == 1) {$sml_full = 'big_smile22';}
if ($myrowtext['cat'] == 2) {$sml_full = 'sml2';}
if ($myrowtext['cat'] == 3) {$sml_full = 'very_bad_smile3';}
if ($myrowtext['cat'] == 4) {$sml_full = 'very_bad_smile22';}

$resultauthor = mysql_query("SELECT id,login,avatar,name,lastname FROM users WHERE id='$myrowtext[author]'",$db); 
$myrowauthor = mysql_fetch_array($resultauthor);

if ($myrowtext == true AND $myrowauthor == true) {
print <<<HERE
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
$("#send_comm").click(function(){
    var author_comm = $("#author_comm").val();
    var text_comm = $("#text_comm").val();
    var post_id = $("#post_id").val();              
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_comment.php",
        data: {"author_comm": author_comm, "text_comm": text_comm, "post_id": post_id},
        cache: false,                       
        success: function(response){
            var messageResp = new Array(' Напишите что-нибудь','Сообщение не отправлено Ошибка базы данных','Нельзя отправлять пустые сообщения');
            var resultStat = messageResp[Number(response)];
            if(response != 0){
                $("#text_comm").val("");
                $("#content_comm").prepend(response);
            }
            $("#resp_comm").text(resultStat).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(400);

        }
    });
    return false;

});
});
</script>

<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='full_p'><tr><td class='full_td_top'>

<img class='prof_photo_full' src='$myrowauthor[avatar]' width='50px' height='50px'></img><span class='full_us_add'>добавил(а) $myrowtext[date]</span><h4 class='prof_name_full'>$myrowauthor[name] $myrowauthor[lastname]</h4><span class='set_prof'><img src='img/sml/$sml_full.png'></img></span></td></tr><tr><td class='full_td'><p>$myrowtext[news]</p>
</td></tr><tr><td><p>Добавить комментарий</p>
<form action='add_comment.php' method='post' name='comm_form'>
<textarea name='text_comm' id='text_comm' cols='20' rows='2'></textarea>
<input name='author_comm' id='author_comm' type='hidden' value='$myrow2[id]'>
<input name='post_id' id='post_id' type='hidden' value='$myrowtext[id]'>
<a href='#' class='add_post_button'  id='send_comm'>Отправить</a>
</form>
<span class='resp_comm' id='resp_comm'>

<div id='content_comm'></div>

</td></tr></table>
HERE;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Дай хотя бы ссылку на сайт, а то наобум сложно сказать.

Comment: Сайт на локалке пока.

Comment: Кнопка 101010

Comment: Могу посоветовать поставить Firebug и смотреть что там происходит и отлавливать баг...

Comment: (function($){$.fn.extend({limit:function(limit,element){var interval,f;var self=$(this);$(this).focus(function(){interval=window.setInterval(substring,100)});$(this).blur(function(){clearInterval(interval);substring()});substringFunction="function substring(){ var val = $(self).val();var length = val.length;if(length > limit){$(self).val($(self).val().substring(0,limit));}";if(typeof element!='undefined')substringFunction+="if($(element).html() != limit-length){$(element).html((limit-length<=0)?'0':limit-length);}";substringFunction+="}";eval(substringFunction);substring()}})})(jQuery);

Comment: ругается на эту функцию

Comment: Странно что на одной странице добавление комментариев работает, а на другой нет. Хотя открывается одно и то же модальное окно.

Comment: Как интересно бывает отвечать на свои же вопросы? да?

Просто бывают вопросы, ответить на которые не то чтобы никто не может, но почему-то не хочет, по стечению определенных обстоятельств.